# Detect if the user taps on the center of the annotation or on a right UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

On my map I have a `rightCalloutAccessoryView` with a `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`. I would like to detect if the user taps on the center of the annotation or on the `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`. 
For example, if he taps on the center : perform a segue named XYZ, if the taps on the UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure : perform a segued named ABC.

Here is my code. The problem is that the `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` and the annotation  perform the same segue named "infoDetail". I try different configurations with a tag on a `rightCalloutAccessoryView` and on a `leftCalloutAccessoryView` to detect which one is tapped, but how can I detect the center of the annotation with a `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` on the right ?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    MKAnnotationView *aView;
    for (aView in views) {
        if (![aView.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
            MKAnnotationView* annotationView = aView;

            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView.tag = 1;

            annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd]; 
            annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView.tag = 2;
        }
    } }


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    if ([control tag] == 1) {
        // Right Accessory Button Tapped
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"infoDetail" sender:self];

    } else if ([control tag] == 2) {
        // Left Accessory Button Tapped
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"contactDetail" sender:self];
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this with a custom button with a touch gesture on the mapView. I don't thinks it's clean way to handle your project but it worked for me,. And i made this with a custom annotation view SMCalloutView. https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview

```
UIButton *leftDisclosure = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 leftDisclosure.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
topDisclosure.frame = theframeYouWant;

[topDisclosure addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(disclosureTapped:)]];

annotationView.rightAccessoryView = topDisclosure;
```

It's tricky, i hope it will help you.